# What is the solution to this mate in 2 puzzle?

Tags: checkmate, problems

[image]

What could be the answer to it?

Comment: Do you recall where you found this particular problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is a nice little puzzle:

```
3k4/3P4/3Q4/8/8/8/8/4K3 w - - 3 13

1. Qd5 Kc7/Ke7 2. d8=Q# 1-0
```